# NullInjectorError: No provider for t

Tags: angular, angular2-providers

Greeting, I'm trying to build my angular2 project with "ng build --prod --configuration=production", deploy it on ubuntu server and I got this error in the web console :

```
ERROR Error: "StaticInjectorError[t -> t]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[t -> t]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for t!"
    get http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    t http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    t http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    get http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    t http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    t http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    get http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    cm http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    n http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    fm http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    cm http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    get http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    tg http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    Jm http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    Qm http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    kg http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    Og http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    Gg http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    create http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    create http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    bootstrap http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    _moduleDoBootstrap http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    _moduleDoBootstrap http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    i http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    invoke http://192.168.1.168/polyfills.71466010da316f5320a5.js:1
    onInvoke http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    invoke http://192.168.1.168/polyfills.71466010da316f5320a5.js:1
    run http://192.168.1.168/polyfills.71466010da316f5320a5.js:1
    I http://192.168.1.168/polyfills.71466010da316f5320a5.js:1
    invokeTask http://192.168.1.168/polyfills.71466010da316f5320a5.js:1
    onInvokeTask http://192.168.1.168/main.765684076005ff28e8f4.js:1
    invokeTask http://192.168.1.168/polyfills.71466010da316f5320a5.js:1
    runTask http://192.168.1.168/polyfills.71466010da316f5320a5.js:1
    g http://192.168.1.168/polyfills.71466010da316f5320a5.js:1
```

I do a lot of research and it seems that it is the fault of a forgotten provider in AppModule

But I can't find which service...

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatButtonModule, MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { Http } from './service/http.service';
import { ToasterService } from './service/toaster.service';
import { ConnectedGuard } from './service/connected-guard.service';
import { DisconnectedGuard } from './service/disconnected-guard.service';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './view/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './view/register/register.component';
import { IndexComponent } from './view/index/index.component';
import { ResetComponent } from './view/reset/reset.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/services/cookies.service';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RecaptchaModule, RECAPTCHA_SETTINGS, RecaptchaSettings } from 'ng-recaptcha';
import { RecaptchaFormsModule } from 'ng-recaptcha/forms';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { PanelComponent } from './component/panel/panel.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    IndexComponent,
    ResetComponent,
    PanelComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RecaptchaModule,
    RecaptchaFormsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: environment.GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY,
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    CookieService,
    Http,
    ToasterService,
    DisconnectedGuard,
    ConnectedGuard,
    AppRoutingModule,
    {
      provide: RECAPTCHA_SETTINGS,
      useValue: {
        siteKey: environment.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_API_KEY,
      } as RecaptchaSettings,
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[Project tree structure](https://prnt.sc/niumd8)

How can I find the solution, I have no idea how to operate.

Have a good day,

Comment: are you able to run the application locally?

Comment: Try using both `import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`
`import { HttpModule} from '@angular/http';`
...
`imports:[HttpClientModule, HttpModule]`

Comment: Which Angular version are you using?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes, it works (with `ng build`, but I want to deploy it on production...) 
@robert I'm using Angular 7.2.0

Comment: @SouravDutta `import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';` canno't find module... What happens to HttpClient?

Comment: @ShidomaruNeveRage, one suggestion would to look at all constructors of your components to identify which servers are being injected and then verify the modules file to see if they are declared in providers.

Comment: `import { Http } from './service/http.service';` is it correct import, I mean is the class name just Http and not HttpService ?

Comment: @SouravDutta The name of this class is `export class Http {`. It is correct (homemade)

Comment: `/*              
// Temporarily comment out this part (in common.js of node_modules) to pinpoint the error
                new UglifyJSPlugin({
                    sourceMap: buildOptions.sourceMap,
                    parallel: true,
                    cache: true,
                    uglifyOptions,
                }),
              */` from this [thread](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4752#issuecomment-392100468)

Comment: @SouravDutta I don't have common.js in my node_modules

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally found the solution (Thanks @SouravDutta for the clue)

1. Go to `.\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\common.js`
2. Comment the following...

```
/*extraMinimizers.push(new TerserPlugin({
   sourceMap: scriptsSourceMap,
   parallel: true,
   cache: true,
   terserOptions,
}));*/
```

3. Rebuild the project again and check the error (more informations are given now)
   (I had: `EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for CookieOptions!`)
   That's a missing provider in my AppModule.ts

---

To solve that missing provider...

1. I add `CookieOptions` to my `import { CookieService, CookieOptions } from 'angular2-cookie/core';` in AppModule.
2. Add into my provider list `{ provide: CookieOptions, useValue: {} }`

Done.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue developing on **Ionic framework**, using the command `ionic cordova run android --device --prod` for production build and run.I would like to expand on @ShidomaruNeveRage solution. In my case I had to comment out the following code to be able to see a detailed error:

```
  /*extraMinimizers.push(new TerserPlugin({
        sourceMap: scriptsSourceMap,
        parallel: true,
        cache: true,
        chunkFilter: (chunk) => !globalScriptsByBundleName.some(s => s.bundleName === chunk.name),
        terserOptions,
    }), 
    // Script bundles are fully optimized here in one step since they are never downleveled.
    // They are shared between ES2015 & ES5 outputs so must support ES5.
    new TerserPlugin({
        sourceMap: scriptsSourceMap,
        parallel: true,
        cache: true,
        chunkFilter: (chunk) => globalScriptsByBundleName.some(s => s.bundleName === chunk.name),
        terserOptions: {
            ...terserOptions,
            compress: {
                ...terserOptions.compress,
                ecma: 5,
            },
            output: {
                ...terserOptions.output,
                ecma: 5,
            },
            mangle: !mangle_options_1.manglingDisabled && buildOptions.platform !== 'server',
        },
    }));
    */
```

Comment: It would help if you indicated which file that code resides in!

Comment: I added my experience with a similar use case and referred to @Shidomaru NeveRage's solution   https://stackoverflow.com/a/55942814/7485690 , which I also mentioned in the text. From the context it should be obvious that I am talking about the same file.